# Initialize cv::Mat with dynamically allocated data

Tags: c++, opencv

Recently I tried to initialize a `cv::Mat` with dynamically allocated data and failed.

```
// Create matrix
size_t sizeA = 30, sizeB = 30;
double** m = new double*[sizeA];

// Fill matrix with data
for(int i = 0; i < sizeA; i++)
{
    m[i] = new double[sizeB];
    for(int j = 0; j < sizeB; j++)
        m[i][j] = (i + 1) * (j + 1);
}

// Compute step between two vectors (not sizeof(double) * sizeB !)
size_t step = reinterpret_cast<size_t>(m[1]) - reinterpret_cast<size_t>(m[0]);

// Copy to matrix (use clone() to see if the data can be addressed properly)
cv::Mat M = cv::Mat(sizeA, sizeB, CV_64FC1, m[0], step).clone();

// delete allocated data
for(int i = 0; i < sizeA; i++)
    delete[] m[i];
delete[] m;
```

Obviously the step between the rows are not consistent (most of the case it is, but sometimes not) because every row is alloced independently.
To show that I simply checked every row and detected several inconsistent steps:

```
for(int i = 2; i < sizeA; i++)
{
    if(step != reinterpret_cast<size_t>(m[i]) - reinterpret_cast<size_t>(m[i-1]))
    {
        std::cout << "Inconsistent step detected between element " << i-1 << " and " << i << " : ";
        std::cout << reinterpret_cast<size_t>(m[i]) - reinterpret_cast<size_t>(m[i-1]) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

My Question: Is there any way to **dynamically** allocate a **matrix** and passing it to cv::Mat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
double* m = new double[sizeA*sizeB];
size_t step = sizeof(double)*sizeB;
```

Comment: True, it is obviously possible to create an array instead of a matrix and treating it as an array. There are two disadvantages. 1. The adressing is not that intuitive and 2. you force the memory to be in one chunck which might be not available or am I wrong?

Comment: As far as I know that is the standard way of doing it.
1) To get around the akwardness you can create helper methods like `getElement(int row, int col)` or even a class that has an array/vector of pointers that point to the first address of each row.
2) On most platforms I don't think you need to be worry about that. You would have to have very fragmented memory and be awfully close to running out of memory for this to be a concern. Also allocating one single chunk is better for performance.